# Unable to download/share pdf files: Where to reset permissions for PDF files?

Tags: file-permissions, pdf

Very newbie here when it comes to Android.

Using Xiaomi Phone, MIUI Global, 12.5.10
Android: 11 RKQ1.20

While downloading PDF files from whatsapp or Sharing PDF files, i'm getting below error. The Error comes in ALL apps with slightly different error messages, but basically PDF formats get this and no other formats (like docx/jpeg/png all work good)

Many apps like Acrobat Reader reports error like: (Very similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159187/opening-pdf-file-error-this-file-could-not-be-accessed-check-the-location-or-th))

```
"Opening pdf file Error: This file could not be accessed Check the location or the network and try again"
```

I had a look using `adb` tools and did a `pm list permissions` all looks ok, but i'm not an expert but it seems more related to "temporary" caching/file-write to the disk. this is because if I put a PDF file in a directory, then open using any tools, it works perfectly. But if I try to download/share file from another app (like whatsapp/email) then it throws error.

I couldn't find any file assocations/app for PDF nor any place where a file permission is denied for the apps in question (eg Whatsapp/email/acrobat reader). My guess is it is to do with writing temporarily into internal storage

Any help/ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated